# How to pass a char *array (belonging to the user address space) to a tasklet or workqueue in a kernel module?

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, driver, workqueue

I’m writing a device driver. If someone calls the write operation I want it to be deferred (using tasklet or workqueue). The code should be something like that:

```
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t *off) {

      packed_work *the_task;
      the_task = kzalloc(sizeof(packed_work), GFP_ATOMIC);
      if (the_task == NULL) {
         printk(KERN_ERR "%s: tasklet buffer allocation failure\n", MODNAME);
         return -1;
      }

      the_task->buffer = the_task;
      the_task->buff = buff;
      the_task->len = len;

      INIT_WORK(&(the_task->the_work), (void*)deferred_write);
      schedule_work(&the_task->the_work);

      return len;
}

void deferred_write(struct work_struct *data) {
    
      printk(“the text: %s\n”, container_of(data, packed_work, the_work)->buff);

      //copy_from_user(&(the_object->stream_content), container_of(data, packed_work, the_work)->buff, len);

      kfree((void*)container_of(data,packed_work,the_work));   

}
```

And the struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct _packed_work{
    void *buffer;
    const char *buff; 
    size_t len;
    struct work_struct the_work;
} packed_work;
```

The problem is that the kernel crashes. It crashes even before the copy_from_user (that’s why I commented it). In the deferred_write() I can print the length of the string but not the string itself. Is it a problem because the buffer is in the user space memory?

I know that, as a workaround, I can copy the user buffer in the task struct (using the copy_from_user() in the function write()) and then use the strcpy() in the deferred_write() function. But I really would like to use the copy_from_user() in deferred_write(). Is it possible? What can I do?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  There are too many undefined parts in the code you have shown to know where the problem is.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the user code has changed the values in the buffer before deferred_write runs? Or unmapped the buffer? Or if the process has exited?

Comment: You can only use user addresses in the context of the user process.  If you defer the write to a kernel thread, that user process is no longer mapped.

Comment: @stark presumably it is possible to map the user process to do the access. The problem is that the memory contents may have changed.

Comment: @user253751 you are right, I can't use the user buffer because it might change. So, I have to do the copy_from_user in the write function and save the buffer in the kernel space. Thanks!

Comment: There are ways to do asynchronous I/O in Linux, but `write()` is not one of them. Look up POSIX AIO (man 7 aio), Linux native AIO (libaio), and Linux io_uring (liburing).

Answer (score 2):

Even if it is possible (and there is surely a way), the user process has probably changed the contents of the buffer in the time before `deferred_write` runs. Notice that user programs often allocate these buffers on the stack, so they get overwritten when the function that called `write` returns and calls other functions.

Even worse: the user process could have unmapped the buffer, or it could have exited.

So you should not delay reading the buffer. You should read the buffer inside the `write` call and not anywhere else.